# Unable to connect Rpi 3 directly through ethernet windows

Tags: ethernet, windows, wifi-direct

When I type 'ping raspberrypi.mshome.net' it returns an ip address but each ping times out and I can't connect through putty.

I was able to do this before, I've setup the ethernet connection as follows:

[image: screenshot of ethernet sharing]

Comment: Did you setup a static ip on the raspberry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Pi to Windows 10 with Internet Connection Sharing](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63153/connect-pi-to-windows-10-with-internet-connection-sharing)

Comment: I'm confused, what's the question? The author should post the steps they took, any error messages, and a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question (which is vague and incomplete) you are trying to use a Windows machine to provide ICS to the Pi. This would be OK, but you can't then use the same connection to connect to the Pi.

You can have one or the other. (This is not strictly true, advanced configuration on the ICS machine may be possible, but this is NOT a Pi question.)

Comment: All I want to do is go in headless mode by directly connecting the pi to my pc.