# Connect Pi to Windows 10 with Internet Connection Sharing

Tags: networking, windows, internet

I have not been able to find an answer to this anywhere, so I'm posting it here.

Issue: connecting a RPi with the latest Jessie update via Ethernet and using a Windows 10 machine to access the internet via Internet Connection Sharing on another network device (eg WiFi).

Comment: OK Im quite new and in other Stack Exchange areas I didnt have enough rep to answer my own questions, noted for the future, thanks.

Comment: OK reframed as a Q&A

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Thank you for your contribution, however, please note that meta-tags like "answer" or "solved" should not be put in the question title. Accept a working answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in that Windows 10 will always revert to the following IP address and Subnet Mask whenever ICS is enabled:

```
192.168.137.1
255.255.255.0
```

The RPi will not auto-detect this and sets itself with something like:

```
169.154.72.93
255.255.0.0
```

Changing the IP & Subnet on the windows machine will not work, because using ICS will over-ride the settings. So a static IP must be set in the RPi, its important to note this should be done in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` add the following:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.137.2
static routers=192.168.137.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.137.1 8.8.8.8
```

setting the static DNS is critical, and adding the Windows 10 host, then the address of a real DNS server.

This then allows you to directly plug the RPi into Ethernet and have internet available via Windows ICS.

Comment: While I don't doubt that your solution worked, if you set ICS as DHCP server to allocate addresses it should work. I don't have Windows 10, but this works on earlier versions.

Comment: I did a search for your solution, I cant find how its done, can you point me to something?